# Free open-source alternative to Google Drive file synchronization

Tags: file-synchronization, synchronization

I'm looking for a free and open source app for Windows (other desktop and mobile OS support welcome) which can allow me to sync files from and to:

- Internal hard drives;
- External drives (portable HDDs/SSDs and USB flash drives);
- Network locations (Samba shares and the like);
- Remote destinations (FTP, SSH);

Additional features which would be nice:

- Change log which shows what has been recently synchronized;
- Accidental deletion protection (keep backups of deleted files for a certain amount of time or forever until manually deleted);
- File version control;
- Differential (delta) change synchronization (instead of uploading the entire file to remote sync folders, only send the part that changed to save network traffic and hard drive space);
- File system sync status icons to show which files have been synced or which have problems syncing.

Integration with popular cloud sync services not required.

---

Some of my experiences with the apps I've tried so far:

#### OwnCloud and NextCloud

Cannot be used offline on a Windows PC if you don't have a Linux server set up.

#### SyncThing

Does not allow you to sync files between folders on the same device (or at least I haven't figured out how). Running the app means having a console window taking space in taskbar and cannot be minimized to tray.

#### FreeFileSync

Works but is not convenient. Automatic syncing is supported via setting up Task Scheduler triggers such as "every hour" or a custom event, possibly you could set up a file system change event in the target folders, but this is not exactly easy to do for a regular user.